# RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers , without declaring as a root view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

i want to swipe between view controllers inside a tab bar. but when i declare its a root view controller, tab bar also hide and user not able to navigate between tab bars. 
how can i achieve this without declaring it as a root view controllers.

```
UIPageViewController *pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers *navigationController = [[RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers alloc]initWithRootViewController:pageController];

//%%% DEMO CONTROLLERS
UIViewController *demo = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIViewController *demo2 = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIViewController *demo3 = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIViewController *demo4 = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
demo.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
demo2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
demo3.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
demo4.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[navigationController.viewControllerArray addObjectsFromArray:@[demo,demo2,demo3,demo4]];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = navigationController;
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: What happens if you remove last two lines, and connect `RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers` to your `TabViewController`

Comment: i already connected a view controller to tab bar and all is doing in this controller . how can i assign  RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers to any connected view controller

Comment: It seems that `RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers` is controlling contents of pageView. Why not directly inherit from `RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers` for your connected view controller. From github repo you're using, read the 'StoryBoard' way of setting things up. You should try to connect a navigation controller as a child of your tab controller and follow the rest.

Comment: how can i achieve this without declare a rootview controller,  its working fine but tab bar is not showing,

Comment: @zcui93 , but according to storyboard way how i will insert pageview controller inside navigation controller. and i can not assign.  confusing this line "Embed a UIPageViewController inside a UINavigationController. Change the class of the to UINavigationController the custom class (RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers)" can you clear me

Comment: Drag a page view controller to storyboard, select it, choose from the menu, embed -> navigation controller, control drag from your tab controller to the new appeared navigation one.

Answer (score 1):

Below these lines of code you can add and swipe between view controllers.

```
[yourView addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self addChildViewController:navigationController];
[navigationController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```